# AWS EC2 and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS. I'm using AWS Lambda to run small scripts, I created 8 different functions in Lamdba. My issue is that I always have multiple instances running all day eventhough my scripts aren't running.
I go here to check my instances (https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/v2/home?region=us-east-1#Instances:sort=instanceState)
and I see 18, when I stop all the running instances new ones get created and I have no idea since why. 
Why is this happening?

Comment: are the instances in `autoscale` group?

Comment: @helloV no they're not,i checked the auto scaling tab and don't see anything there

Answer (score 1):

If you have `CloudTrail` (which is free) enabled, go to CloudTrail dashboard you will see `why/when/who` started the instances (look for `StartInstances/RunInstances`) and it will give you a clue on what is happening.

Comment: Thanks I was able to figure it out.

Comment: Can you share what you found?

Comment: I had a data pipeline running every 15 minutes that I had started in the beginning of the month and forgot to stop

Answer (score 0):

There are two possible reasons for the issue:

- Your Lambda functions launch new instances. Review code of all your functions and make sure that you have solid understanding of what this functions do
- You have an auto-scaling group that launches new instances for you.
  More information about this feature here:
  https://aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/

Comment: Thanks for the reply Vlad, my code doesnt launch new instances I wouldn't even know how to do it. I checked the autoscaling and there's nothing there either.

Comment: In this case, Create a CloudFormation template using [this guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-using-cloudformer.html) and post you template here. This information should be more than enough to identify the reason with 100% accuracy. Note, we will not be able to see your data, only the information about what instances and what resources you are using.